# Trying to run a project using a specified domain in IIS instead of localhost using visual studio 2012 on windows 7 professional 64bit

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, iis, visual-studio-2012

Right this is my first post so apologies if i haven't included enough information on the matter; just let me know and i can provide more information if need be.

---

Initially the project failed to load and i got this error:

The Web Application Project is configured to use IIS. Unable to access the IIS metabase. You do not have sufficient privilege to access IIS web sites on your machine

---

So then I ran Visual Studio as Administrator and it now loads the project but nothing loads into the web browser. It finds the domain but nothing loads and an error 500 internal server error is received.

---

I've set up the domain in IIS and connected it to the project, and I've changed the host files for the domain name.

---

Additional info:
-using .net v4.0 
-visual studio 2012
-c# mvc 4 web application project
-windows 7 professional

I've been looking for solutions for the past two days and now I'm stuck I feel like I have tried everything. If anyone else knows of this problem or knows of a solution or can point me in the right direction any help would be greatly appreciated! Thank you!

Comment: Is the application pool that the site is running under configured to use  .Net Framework 4.0?

Comment: yes it's all set up to use .net 4.0

Comment: If you run it off a different port without using a host header, does it work? i.e. `http://localhost:400`. If you get a 500 error, can you post a stack trace?

Comment: it works fine on localhost but for the project i'm working on i need it to be going through a specified domain,

Comment: Can you verify the settings you have for the site bindings within IIS? Type, IP Address, Port and Host name

Comment: ok now it's working but im getting this error: Parser Error Message: Could not load file or assembly 'MySql.Web, Version=6.7.4.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

Comment: I had to set up the username and password on iis so it could access the project, silly mistake, but yeah not i'm getting that error

Comment: Ensure that `Copy Local` set to true on the `MySql.Web` reference and that the correct version is in the bin folder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hey guys thanks for all your help I eventually found the solution. For some reason static content had been disabled by default on IIS. Once I enabled that everything started to work fine.

For anyone else with a similar problem go to control panel>>programs>>programs and features>>turn windows features on or off>>Internet Information Services>>World Wide Web services>>Common HTTP Features and then ensure that Static Content is checked/enabled.